# I'm trying to make an API request in node using snekfetch, but return is not what was expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I have is

```
const fetch = require('snekfetch');
fetch.get('https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Dad-12262/stats')
    .then(r => console.log(r.body));
```

The log I get is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BSYF.png)

However when I visit the link in my browser I get a whole slew of information. I'm not sure what I'm missing from my request.

Comment: There's nothing missing. It's just the other information is in the request you see are in the properties `competitive` and `quickplay` which are not shown in the terminal *but it's there if you access it*

Comment: I thought that and tried console.log(r.body.competitive) but that doesn't seem to be right. I'm having trouble finding any documentation or resources to learn how to make this request properly. Do you know of a good resource I can use to learn?

Comment: It works fine for me, you're just accessing the wrong property: `snek.get('https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Dad-12262/stats').then(r => r.body).then(x => console.log("snek", x.us.stats.competitive));`

Comment: I see. Thank you for that.

Now I must find a way to set variables within .then so I can set r.body.us.stats etc to a variable, that way I can access everything with variable.level etc, since what I have now is a mess repeating everything over and over for my log.

Or would saving to a json for reference be easier?

currently (lol) :
https://gyazo.com/6a412657ca7bc2254dce356b7bb4c9a7